# Will simple random walk on $n$-cycle converges to Brownian motion on $S^1$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, brownian-motion, markov-process, random-walk

I know that, by Donsker's theorem, simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ will converge to Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$. Here, simple random walk means that the Markov chain with probability from $n$ to $n+1$, and from $n$ to $n-1$ are equally $1/2$.

Then, we can consider similar random walk on $n$-cycle. More rigorously, consider $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and suppose probability from $n$ to $n+1$, and from $n$ to $n-1$ are equally $1/2$. Then, as $n$ increases this will also converges to Brownian motion on $S^1$? (Here, Brownian motion on $S^1$ is the Markov process induced by the heat kernel)

If it is true, probably we will need to rescale the original random walk. Since the simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ does not consider geometry of $S^1$.

Maybe this is classical question, but I couldn't find good references. Is there any book about "convergence of Random walk to Brownian motion on manifolds(Or, just $S^1$)"?

Comment: So you want $n$ going to $\infty$; does $k$ go to $\infty$ as well? If $k < \frac{n}{8}$ then this of course reduces of course to the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. If $k$ is much larger than $n$ then of course this reduces to the uniform distribution (almost, if $n$ is even parity will be preserved, so for $n$ even uniform on the evens or odds depending on which step of the walk)

Comment: $k$ means the number of transition, I guess? How about the parabolic scaling $k=n^2$?

Comment: Yes I meant $k$ is the number of transitions. But for any even $n$, parity will still be preserved. So $n$ odd?

Comment: Yes. Let's assume $n$ is odd if necessary. Moreover we can use spectral expansion if $n$ is odd, which is probably good thing..?

Comment: For $n$ odd the only eigenvector w normalized eigenvalue that has absolute value exactly 1 is the vector on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ that is 1 everywhere--and the eigenvalue is 1, for $n$ even the eigenvector w normalized eigenvalue exactly -1 is the vector that is -1 on the odds and 1 on the evens

Comment: spectral expansion does kick in strongly by $k \approx 4n^2 \log n$ I am not sure about $k \approx n^2$ though

Comment: In any event it is looking like the hard case is for $\frac{n^2}{\log n} \le k \le n^2 \log n$.

Comment: Mike, can you explain your intuition with more detail? how do you get $k\sim 4n^2log n $?

Comment: For $k$ above (say) $4n^2 \log n$ (and $n$ odd) then $k$ is large enough so that the spectral inequalities will guarantee something close to the uniform distribution. For $k$ that large and $n$ even, then it is something close to the uniform distribution on the evens or the odds depending on the parity of $k$. I am not positive on the constant 4 btw

Comment: For $k$ smaller than $\frac{n^2}{\log n}$ the probability mass wrapping back around will be negligibly small, and this is more or less like working on $\mathbb{Z}$.